# Computing Previously Aligned Address

Tags: c++

To get the next aligned address, given a pointer and an alignment, ppl use:

```
inline int OffsetRequiredForAlignment( uintptr_t address_p, int alignment_p ){

    uintptr_t mask = alignment_p - 1;
    uintptr_t amountMisaligned = (address_p & mask );
    int offset = (int)(alignment_p - amountMisaligned);

    if( offset == alignment_p ) offset = 0;

    return offset;
}
```

Or some variation of that.
How do you compute the previous aligned address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The next aligned address is `address_p + offset`. The previous aligned address is `address_p - amountMisaligned`.

Also, offset should probably be:

```
int offset = (alignment_p - int(amountMisaligned)) & int(mask);
```

Then you can eliminate the if statement.